# How to remove duplicate slashes from file path

Tags: php

This question HAS been asked before and got closed WITHOUT any answers

Second time lucky, my previous question got closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903375/php-clean-up-path-with-duplicate-slashes looks like I was missing the question mark to make it obvious what my question was.

QUESTION:

1. How can I remove the duplicate slashes from a string? See code below with examples.
2. How well does windows(wamp) support file paths using forward slashes? It feels wrong writing c:/wamp but appears to work fine as the reason why I am unsure.

CODE:

```
<?php
function clean($full_path){
    return str_replace(array("\\", "//", "\/", "/\"), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $full_path);
}

$paths = array(
 'var/www/tpl//main.tpl',
 'C:\wamp\www\/tpl\\main.tpl',
 'C:\wamp\www/\tpl\main.tpl');

 foreach($paths as $path){
     echo "Before: $url\nAfter:  ".clean($path)."\n---------------------\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: 10$ someone is going to close this one as well

Comment: How come? I really dont get what peoples problem is on here people prefer to nit-pick over your question then actually help you out with the code

Comment: You are escaping `"` in the last `"/\"` one

Comment: @JohnMagnolia wamp uses `__FILE__` constant which gives you the path of file it's inbuilt in php

Comment: I am very sure that this has been asked before. Please use the search. Also please only ask one question at a time, that works much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape backslashes. Try this:

```
<?php

function clean($full_path){
    return str_replace(array(
        "\\\\",
        "\\/", 
        "//", 
        "\\/", 
        "/\\"), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $full_path);
}

$paths = array(
 'var/www/tpl//main.tpl',
 'C:\wamp\www\/tpl\\main.tpl',
 'C:\wamp\www/\tpl\main.tpl');

 foreach($paths as $path){
     echo "Before: $path <br/> After:  ".clean($path)."<br/>---------------------<br/>";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How well does windows(wamp) support file paths using forward slashes? It feels wrong writing c:/wamp but appears to work fine as the reason why I am unsure.

PHP supports this very well. Actually since years, and you can just use it, instead of the [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/dir.constants) as it helps for easily write cross-platform code.

Take care howeever that this is a network share in WAMP:

```
\\host\share\path\to\file.ext
```

So "just" removing double slashes is actually a bad idea. What you might want is called [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `preg_match();` or `str_replace();`.